# Error for pygame.draw.lines()

Tags: python, pygame, draw

```
pygame.draw.lines(Field2, BLACK, True, LON, width = 2)
```

When I put this code into my program it returns this error:

```
 pygame.draw.lines(Field2, BLACK, True, LON, width = 2)
 TypeError: lines() takes no keyword arguments
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You should give function `lines` a keyword argument (`width=2`).
Invoke function `lines` like this:

```
pygame.draw.lines(Field2, BLACK, True, LON, 2)
```

Here is [**link**](http://nullege.com/codes/search?cq=pygame.draw.lines) for how to use this function.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

```
lines(Surface, color, closed, pointlist, width=1)
```

`width` has a default value of 1; these are not keyword arguments. Try this:

```
pygame.draw.lines(Field2, BLACK, True, LON, 2)
```